# Implementing search in Laravel: Call to a member function posts() on null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to implement a category/subreddit search in Laravel 5 but I'm not getting any results with my queries.

I keep getting this error:

> Call to a member function posts() on null

Search route I'm using

```
Route::resource('subreddit', 'SubredditController');
Route::post('search', ['as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'SubredditController@search']);
```

When I search for something it redirects me to `localhost/reddit/search`

I'd love if it can redirect to `localhost/reddit/subreddit/{id}/search`

This is `search()` function in `SubredditController`

```
public function search(Request $request, Subreddit $subreddit) {
    $query = Input::get('search');
    $subreddit = Subreddit::with('posts.votes')->with('moderators.user')->where('id', $subreddit->id)->first();
    $posts = $subreddit->posts()->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
    $posts->setPath($subreddit->id);

    return view('subreddit.search', compact('query', 'subreddit', 'posts'));
}
```

`dd($subreddit)` give null

I don't understand why it's returning null when the same query works on the `show()` method.

`RouteServiceProvider`

```
$router->model('subreddit', 'App\Subreddit');
$router->model('posts', 'App\Post');
$router->model('moderators', 'App\Moderator');
```

Routes I'm using

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::resource('votes', 'VotesController');
Route::resource('subreddit', 'SubredditController');
Route::resource('subreddit.moderators', 'ModeratorsController');
Route::get('mysubreddits', [
    'as' => 'mysubreddits',
    'uses' => 'SubredditController@mySubreddits'
]);
Route::post('search', ['as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'SubredditController@search']);
```

**EDIT:** So I am now getting the correct result when I replace `$subreddit->id` with `24` which is the id of the subreddit I am viewing. Why am I unable to use `$subreddit->id` while I can in the `show()` method of the same controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using route model binding. If you are, there's no reason to reload your subreddit from the database.

Call `load` on `$subreddit` to [eager load your relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading):

```
public function search(Request $request, Subreddit $subreddit)
{
    $query = $request->input('search');

    $subreddit->load(['posts.votes', 'moderators.user']);

    $posts = $subreddit->posts()->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
                       ->paginate()->setPath($subreddit->id);

    return view('subreddit.search', compact('query', 'subreddit', 'posts'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I stopped receiving any errors and the search view is loading but without any results. No search result, not even the subreddit name. This is how I'm displaying the subreddit name `{{ $subreddit->name }}`` and how I'm iterating through the posts `@foreach($posts as $post)` but it's all empty.

Comment: @Halnex - Are you using route model binding? What do you get for `dd($subreddit->id)`?

Comment: yes I am using route-model-binding. I get `null` when I `dd($subreddit->id)`

Comment: Then your route model binding is wrong. Can you show us the binding and route you're using?

Comment: @Halnex - your route doesn't accept a subreddit ID.

Comment: I see. Should the route be `Route::post('subreddit/{id}/search')` or what would it look like?

Comment: @Halnex - Yes. `Route::post('subreddit/{subreddit}/search')`

Comment: this is giving `NotFoundHttpException` and the URI in the browser points to `localhost/reddit/public/subreddit/%7Bsubreddit%7D/search`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91986/discussion-between-joseph-silber-and-halnex).

Comment: I kept tinkering, and found out your load method does not retrieve any results. so I went back to the old way and manually inserted the subreddit.id like this `$subreddit = Subreddit::with('posts.votes')->with('moderators.user')->where('id', 24)->first();` this will retrieve all posts in subreddit 24, but I'm still unable to use $subreddit->id, why is that?